# Measure theory and that have solution manuals

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I am trying to find a book to learn measure theory that contains complete solutions manual. Does someone know of any?

Comment: [Measures, Integrals and Martingales](http://www.amazon.com/Measures-Integrals-Martingales-Ren-Schilling/dp/0521615259/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414958001&sr=8-1&keywords=measure+martingale)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497009/measure-theory-and-topology-books-that-have-solution-manuals