# Looking for a problem and answer book for measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Looking supplementary self-study texts for measure theory, including a good problem and solutions companion while studying Royden and Stein's ***Real Analysis***.  Instructors solutions for either would work as well .

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497009/70305)

Answer (score 4):

1) Alberto Torchinsky, *Problems in Real and Functional Analysis*.

2) Charalambos D. Aliprantis, *Problems in Real Analysis*.

3) Claude George, *Exercises in Integration*.

4) J. Yeh, *Problems and Proofs in Real Analysis*.

5) Bernard R. Gelbaum, *Problems in Real and Complex Analysis*.

6) Bernard R. Gelbaum, *Problems in Analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

***Problems and Solutions for Undergraduate Real Analysis II*** by Kit-Wing Yu.